# Removing reference "&" from new Object causes unexpected issues in PHP

Tags: php

I'm maintaining some legacy code and I've been removing references to new objects along the way like:

```
$object = & new SomeObject();
```

to this:

```
$object = new SomeObject();
```

And this, despite the fact that it shouldn't make any difference since PHP5 did mess up some things pretty bad with the object not beeing a reference anymore at all. If the `&` is replaced in there the issues vanish.

Here is an example code:

```
<?php

class TreeNode
{
    public $subtree;
    public $name;
    public $layer;
    public $children;

    function &addNode(&$node)
    {
        $this->children[] = &$node;
    }

}

$subtree = array(array('bla','blubb'), 'foo');

$tree = new TreeNode();
$tree->subtree = $subtree;
$tree->layer = 0;
$tree->name = 'root';

$b = buildTree($tree);

print_r($b);

function &buildTree(&$tree) {
    if(is_array($tree->subtree))
    {
        foreach($tree->subtree as $key => $subtree)
        {
            $node = new TreeNode(); ///#### This line is a toggle and it's unknown why
            $node->layer = $tree->layer + 1;
            $node->subtree = $subtree;
            $tree->addNode( buildTree($node) );
            unset($tree->subtree[$key]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $tree->name = $tree->subtree;
    }

    return $tree;
}

?>
```

If the line is `$node = new TreeNode();`, output is:
    TreeNode Object
    (
        [subtree] => Array
            (
            )

```
    [name] => root
    [layer] => 0
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => TreeNode Object
                (
                    [subtree] => foo
                    [name] => foo
                    [layer] => 1
                    [children] => 
                )

            [1] => TreeNode Object
                (
                    [subtree] => foo
                    [name] => foo
                    [layer] => 1
                    [children] => 
                )

        )

)
```

If the line is `$node = & new TreeNode();` the output is:
    TreeNode Object
    (
        [subtree] => Array
            (
            )

```
    [name] => root
    [layer] => 0
    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => TreeNode Object
                (
                    [subtree] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [name] => 
                    [layer] => 1
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => TreeNode Object
                                (
                                    [subtree] => bla
                                    [name] => bla
                                    [layer] => 2
                                    [children] => 
                                )

                            [1] => TreeNode Object
                                (
                                    [subtree] => blubb
                                    [name] => blubb
                                    [layer] => 2
                                    [children] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => TreeNode Object
                (
                    [subtree] => foo
                    [name] => foo
                    [layer] => 1
                    [children] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it turned out to be an issue caused by even more references. The code in question looked something like this:

```
function &recursiveFunction(&$someobject) {
  $object = & new SomeObject();
  $someobject->recursiveFunction($object);
  return $someobject;
}
```

And removing the references from the function and everywhere the object was used solved the issues finally without having to have a reference on the creation too. So it was only partly an issue of the reference itself but other references around too.

```
function recursiveFunction($someobject) {
  $object = new SomeObject();
  $someobject->recursiveFunction($object);
  return $someobject;
}
```

I'm still somewhat unsure as of exactly why this did happen but it's probably some issue with PHP internals handling `&$object` still differently than `$object` even if in the newer versions objects should always be references to the object itself.

Comment: There are no issues with internal handling whatsoever, and posting the error(s) you get next time you ask questions might help others to tell you what went wrong, why it went wrong and how to avoid it.

Comment: The issue was the function seemingly returning a reference to the same object for all the objects then. So all objects returned would be the same object in the end. We used this to render a navigation tree and when the `&` at the new was removed it displayed the same text&link on all the nodes as all the nodes have gotten the content of the last node created by the function. If either all the & are in place or none of them it works correctly.

Comment: I've added some example code that exhibits the same issue so you can experiment with it. It pretty stumped me as afaik there shouldn't be any difference anymore for objects passed with or without a reference.